# R - Summarize course enrollment over relative term sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence, purrr

### The Applied Problem

I want to abstract out code that summarizes course taking patterns and success rates of a cohort of students for *n* courses and *n* terms.

### Example

With the following cohort of students, how many go to course "B"  *after* taking Course "A", and how many of those students succeeded:

```
data <- data.frame(student = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                   term    = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4),
                   course  = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C'),
                   success = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We can answer that question with the following code:

```
library(dplyr) 

# Get each student's first, second, third, ... term.
    data <- data %>%
      group_by(student) %>%
      mutate(term_dense = dense_rank(term))%>%
      ungroup()

# Identify those who took course A
    courseA <- data %>%
      filter(course == "A")%>%
      select(student, courseA_dense = term_dense)

# Get records of students who took course A, and their subsequent courses
    data <- data %>%
      left_join(courseA, by = "student")%>%
      filter(term_dense >= courseA_dense) # >= for courses they took in same term as course "A"

# Summarise for each term_dense
    data %>%
      group_by(term_dense) %>%
      summarise(attempted_course_A = sum(course == "A"),
                completed_course_A = sum(course == "A" & success == 1),
                attempted_course_B = sum(course == "B"),
                completed_course_B = sum(course == "B" & success == 1))
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term_dense attempted_course_A completed_course_A attempted_course_B completed_course_B
       <int>              <int>              <int>              <int>              <int>
1          1                  4                  2                  0                  0
2          2                  2                  2                  2                  2
3          3                  0                  0                  0                  0
```

and we can see that of the students who attempted course A, that 2 attempted course B, both of which succeeded.

Now, I could calculate how many took course "C" *after* taking course "A" by adding lines in the `summarise` statement (i.e. `completed_course_C = sum(course == "C" & success == 1)`), but if I have a lot of courses, it doesn't seem like the most efficient option.

Furthermore, if I want to summarise the sequence of course "X" *after* course "Y", for any "X" and "Y", it creates even more permutations of `summarise` statements. And how do I look at those who took "X" *after* "Y" *after* "Z".

So, **how do I summarise course progression and success rates for a variable amount of courses over a variable amount of terms?**

### Desired Output

I think this is where some of my difficulty lies. I don't know what the resulting `data.frame` needs to be structured like.

I do know that I would like to easily answer the following general question, though:

"X% of students who were successful in course "A", subsequently took course "B" and had a success rate of Y%"

### Abstract Problem

I have been trying to apply the general problem (cohort tracking / sequencing?) to other fields, in order to get better key words / search results in google and Stack Overflow. One that has seemed promising is using network analysis.

Specifically, [this post, Network Analysis with R](https://www.jessesadler.com/post/network-analysis-with-r/), was helpful in identifying a potential solution. I followed along this article, using my data instead, and was able to get out about half of my information. Using that method, I was only able to get either a sequence of attempts, or a sequence of success rates - not both. But I've only just begun learning about network analysis.

Actually, I have been able to manually visualize a summary using [`plotly`'s sankey diagram](https://plot.ly/r/sankey-diagram/), which uses a similar network/link framework. But I still haven't been able to programmatically calculate that information.

### Other attempts

Given that I want to essentially 'map' a summary function to my data, many of my attempts have used the `purrr` package with nested list-columns.

#### `purrr` attempts

Using the original `data` from above, I tried to nest a students list of courses, per their ranked terms.

```
# library(dplyr) # Loaded in above example
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)    

data <- data %>%
      group_by(student) %>%
      mutate(term_dense = dense_rank(term)) %>%
      ungroup()%>%
      nest(term, course, success, .key = "schedule")
```

Then I tried to create a function that would return a summary for a source course to a target course, with the ultimate goal to be to `map` this function to a list that contains all unique permutations of source and target:

```
attempt_summary <- function(df, source, target){

  temp_df <- df %>%
                filter(map_lgl(schedule, ~any(.x$course == source)))%>%
                select(student, source_term_dense = term_dense)

  df <- df %>%
        left_join(temp_df, by = "student")%>%
        filter(term_dense >= source_term_dense)

  df %>%
    group_by(term_dense) %>%
    summarise(completed_source = sum(map_int(schedule, ~any(.x$course == source & .x$success == 1))),
              attempted_target = sum(map_int(schedule, ~any(.x$course == target))),
              completed_target = sum(map_int(schedule, ~any(.x$course == target & .x$success == 1))))

}
```

The function works for one example,

```
attempt_summary(data, "A", "B")

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  term_dense completed_source attempted_target completed_target
       <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>
1          1                2                0                0
2          2                2                2                2
3          3                0                0                0
```

but I couldn't figure out how to map it to everything else (I couldn't even figure out how to structure my target and source lists) but here was my attempt:

```
# DO NOT RUN - DOESN'T WORK
# map(data, attempt_summary, source = src_list, target = trgt_list)
```

#### Stack Overflow Posts

In addition to many others about `purrr`, I referenced these posts in looking for a solution, but none of was what I was looking for.

- [Tracking cohort over time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45847641/9017311)
- [Sequence Analysis of Consumer Baskets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45555104/9017311)

### Session Info

Here is the output from my `sessionInfo()` call:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] purrr_0.3.2   tidyr_0.8.3   dplyr_0.8.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       fansi_0.4.0      utf8_1.1.4       crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1 R6_2.4.0        
 [7] magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.3.1     cli_1.1.0        rlang_0.3.4      rstudioapi_0.10  tools_3.5.3     
[13] glue_1.3.1       compiler_3.5.3   pkgconfig_2.0.2  tidyselect_0.2.5 tibble_2.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one slice at your question in the middle about "X% of students who were successful in course "A", subsequently took course "B" and had a success rate of Y%".

This finds the Y% for each course A successful and each course A not successful.

```
library(tidyverse)
data2 <- data %>%
  left_join(data, by = c("student")) %>%   # add future course results to each result that has any
  filter(term.y > term.x) %>%  # includes all future courses; could limit to just next one?
  count(course.x, success.x, course.y, success.y) %>%
  spread(success.y, n, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(success_rate = `1`/ (`0` + `1`)) %>%
  select(course.x:course.y, success_rate) %>%
  spread(course.y, success_rate)
```

Results:  each "event 1" as a row, and success rate for future class Y in each column. This shows that people who took A passed all subsequent courses, regardless of how they did in A. People who took B had a 50-50 pass rate on C.

```
> data2
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  course.x success.x     A     B     C
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A                0     1    NA   1  
2 A                1    NA     1   1  
3 B                1    NA    NA   0.5
```